# Minimizing Integration Error in an Accelerometer

Tags: signal-analysis, sensor

I am trying to use an accelerometer in an IMU (ISM330DHCX) (integrating to get position). To do this I need to fix the calibration error. Ideally the integral of the accelerometer values while static would be 0. I am not getting this however, and get runaway error in the integral. My current method takes the average of a portion of data and subtracts this value from the accelerometer to try to remove the bias error. If the noise was random I would expect this to work, as any further noise would be equally distributed in the positive and negative direction.

Answer (score 2):

You can calibrate out the offset at a specific point in time, but drift will be inevitable. The more expensive the sensor, the lower the drift will be and the longer you can go without another reference such as GPS. Vendors will provide this information, typically as an Allan Deviation (ADEV) plot where the duration of time where drift effects will not be an issue can be determined by the minimum of ADEV vs tau (referred to as the flicker floor or bias instability floor).